# Why my ReactNavigation StackNavigation throws error

Tags: react-native

I have a beginner problem.
I'm trying to create a route system using the react navigation, I create the StackNavigator, but I get an error that does not make much sense to me

I'm using React-Navigation 3.x and React-native 0.59 on android

routes.js

```js
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './screens/Home'

const Routes = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
})

export default createAppContainer(Routes)
```

Home.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

index.js (src)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Routes from './routes'

export default class App extends Component {
    render () {
        return <Routes />
    }
}
```

index.js (root)

```js
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Console log

```js
ReferenceError: ReferenceError: View is not defined

This error is located at:
  in NavigationContainer (at src/index.js:9)
  in App (at renderApplication.js:35)
  in RCTView (at View.js:45)
  in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
  in RCTView (at View.js:45)
  in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
  in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with your code, but the error sounds like something's wrong with your <View> component, not react navigation. Does it render properly without react navigation? Try deleting package-lock.json and your node_modules folder and giving it a fresh npm install

Comment: Try to change `const Routes` to `const temp` and then `const Routes = createAppContainer(temp)` and then export that Routes like : `export default Routes`.